# How to filter for un-empty array in CUBA Platform collection

Tags: cuba-platform

I need to call a collection consisting of objects that have an un-empty array in the items (array) field, I filter collection like this:

```
filter:
conditions:[
{
              property: "items",
              operator: "notEmpty",
              value:null
            }]
```

but this solution doesn't work, 500 error is returned, how to implement it?

Answer (score 1):

CUBA Platform REST API doesn't support filtration by collections (`@OneToMany` and `@ManyToMany` relations).

To implement such functionality you need to [create and expose predefined JPQL query on back end](https://doc.cuba-platform.com/restapi-7.2/?&_ga=2.255609675.2101666762.1644320462-91543178.1638799326#rest_api_v2_queries_config).

There is [similar discussion on CUBA Platform forum](https://forum.cuba-platform.com/t/rest-api-filter-with-nested-properties-in-react-front-end/14649).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).